# Find the solution of the initial value problem

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Find the solution of the initial value problem:

a) $x \, \dfrac{dy}{dx}-y=x+x^2, \ \ x>0 \ \text{ and } \ y(1)=2. $

Comment: Since you're working on $]0,+\infty[$, you can divide by $x$ and proceed as you'd normally do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}-\frac{y}{x}=1+x$$

Use the  substitution: 
$$u = \frac{y}{x} $$

$$y=xu \Rightarrow y'=u+xu'$$

So,you have, $$u+xu'-u=1+x \Rightarrow xu'=1+x \Rightarrow u'=\frac{1+x}{x} \Rightarrow \frac{du}{dx}=\frac{1+x}{x} \Rightarrow du=\frac{1}{x}+1 \Rightarrow u=lnx +x+c$$

$$y=xlnx+x^2+xc$$

$$y(1)=2 \Rightarrow 1+c=2 \Rightarrow c=1$$

Therefore, $y=xlnx+x^2+x$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Divide by $x$ to obtain $$\frac{dy}{dx} - \frac{1}{x}y = 1 + x$$Now solve by multiplying by the method of [integrating factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :**
\begin{align}
xy'-y&=x+x^2\\
\frac{xy'-y}{x^2}&=\frac{x+x^2}{x^2}\\
\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac yx\right)&=\frac1x+1\\
\int\ d\left(\frac yx\right)&=\int \left(\frac1x+1\right)\ dx.
\end{align}